# Check Screen Width then all Urls on the page Redirect to mobile if

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, .htaccess

I am a newbie to jQuery / javascript and I had this working without checking the window size first. Then messed around with it and can not get it to work. The redirect is supposed to replace `mysite.com/index.php?querystring` with `mysite.com/mobile.php?querystring` if screen size is less then 699. Please help. Thank You.

This function seems to work exaclty how I need it but need to have onload with if screen size is less then.

```
$('a').each(function(index, a) {
    var href = $(a).attr('href');
    $(a).attr('href', 'http://mysite.com/mobile.php?redirect=' + href;)
}
```

}

//below is not working

```
function checkWidth() {
    var windowSize = $(window).width();
    if (windowSize <= 699) {

window.onload = function() {
    /* onload code */
    // Execute on load
    //checkWidth();{

var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

    for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
    anchors[i].href = "http://mysite.com/mobile.php?redirect=" + anchors[i].href

    /* function checkWidth() {
    var windowSize = $(window).width();*/
}
}
```

Comment: Apart from getting the width of the screen, you're not actually using any jQuery here.

Comment: the issue is probably with the `window.onload` being defined inside the `checkWidth` function call

Answer (score 2):

If you intend on using jQuery, this should work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var window_width = $(window).width();

    if( window_width < 699 ) {
        $('a').each(function(index, a) {
            var href = $(a).attr('href');
            $(a).attr('href', 'http://mysite.com/mobile.php?redirect=' + href;
        }); 
    }
});
```

Comment: It looks like that would work or what I am looking for but it is not working. At least it does not break anything.

Comment: What doesn't work? I'm guessing you're resizing the window after the page load? Does it work if you resize window prior to loading the page?

Comment: The sizing is ok. But the links are not changing onload from mysite.com/index.php?querystring to mysite.com/mobile.php?querystring

Answer (score 1):

This is really something you should be doing server-side. Because someone isn't exactly going to be switching the device over the course of the session, you should check the device when they first visit the site, and then create a session variable storing it. Then, on every new page have the server check the variable and use it to determine which links to put in. If you're content with doing it client-side, though, Ryan Pilbeam's answer should work.

Comment: Here is the problem. I have a module installed that does everything as needed dynamically. But, some not so smart person decided to hard code a bunch of links all over and they basically take you back to the original site instead of staying on the mobile site.

Comment: The module itself contains the links?